# EntityFramework DatabaseLogger Interceptor cannot be loaded on server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Adding DatabaseLogger Interceptor as per https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/09/ef-6-1-turning-on-logging-without-recompiling/

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="D:\TempLogging\LogOutput.txt"/>
      <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/>
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

Works fine on local, dev and QA boxes but on customer server adding this config throws error

```
The type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework' registered in the application config file as an IDbInterceptor could not be loaded
```

The EntityFramework.dll is in the server's bin directory.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem on this server? Any other things to check?

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if the drive or path to the file is invalid (or not accessible).

```
<parameter value="D:\TempLogging\LogOutput.txt"/>
```

In your case, make sure **drive D:** and **TempLogging** folder exist and writable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happens under IIS APP when multiple threads are trying to access DB. I could not found simple solution, only turning this DBInterceptor-feature off.